# Jface filter using ViewerFilter displays black lines while filtering

Tags: jface

How to avoid the lines which appear in the image while we do a filter operation using jface table viewer using ViewerFilter:
[image: jface table example image]

Comment: This isn't normal. Show us a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to turn off redrawing during the filtering:

```java
viewer.getControl().setRedraw(false);

.. your filter update

viewer.getControl().setRedraw(true);
```